# Override parent class properties typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a parent class `Parent` from a lib with some properties and a child class `Child` which have the same properties but with different types.

```
class Parent {
  propertyA: string;

  propertyB: string;
  
  propertyC: string;

  constructor() {
    this.propertyC = '';
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  propertyA: number;

  propertyB: number;
}
```

I 'm trying to override the type of multiple properties from the parent class but got an error `ts(2416)`.

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I could have change the `Parent` class to an interface and use `Omit<>` to remove `propertyA` and `propertyB` but the class is in a lib.

I can't use composition (`PropertyParent: Parent` as a `Child` property) or change properties name because `Child` will be used to describe existant data (imagine a table with the three properties) as generic type for [firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) library's functions (see the `FirebaseFirestore.CollectionReference<T>` type).

Is there an other way to do so ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Parent {
  propertyA: string | number;

  propertyB: string | number;
  
  propertyC: string;

  constructor() {
    this.propertyC = '';
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  propertyA: number;

  propertyB: number;
}
```

This works because as part of the [criticisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#Criticism) for the duly referenced Liskov substitution principle that is mentioned by @T. J. Crowder, the substitution requirement doesn't consider the need for parent types that are abstract or generic.

So, you should be able to browse to the library's source code and do this, if necessary, you can also cast code that's to use the parent's types as string by using typescript's `as` keyword.

Comment: It would have been a great workaround but I can't edit the parent class as mentionned in my question.

Comment: If this is not a private npm package as I believe firebase npm libraries aren't, you would be able to overwrite the package as another published custom package having the type definitions suggested and then use [npm overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) once your npm version is v8.3 or older or better still overwrite the specific file containing the parent class definition in the npm package by using this npm package called [overwrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/overwrite?activeTab=readme)

Answer (score 4):

If `Parent`'s `propertyA` is of type `string`, `Child`'s `propertyA` must also be of type `string`, because of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). A `Child` has to "be a" `Parent`, and that means that code with a `Parent` reference to a `Child` object must be able to treat it as though it were a `Parent` object. That code will expect a `string`, not a `number`.

Since that's not the case for what you're doing, inheritance probably isn't the appropriate approach. You might try composition instead: `Child` could have a field of type `Parent`.

Alternatively, have `Child` leave `propertyA` alone and have another property for the `number`.

Comment: sadly I can't use composition, I use the child type as a generic with an other lib (firebase) to define the model of a document. I need the properties of parent in child and I can't leave propertyA because it's part of the model

Comment: Nice explanation! +1