# Override type of property inherited from parent class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, extend

I'm very curious about how to do this, my goal is to inherit all the functionality of a base class and modify or extend it, for example:

```
class myFirstClass {
   attr1: string;
   attr2: number;

   constructor(){
      this.attr1 = 'test';
      this.attr2 = 1;
  }

  firstMethod(){
    console.log("test1");
  }

}

class mySecondClass extends myFirstClass {
  attr1: boolean; // I wish to update the type of this variable, which typescript won't let me [Property 'attr1' in type 'mySecondClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'myFirstClass'.]

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.attr1 = true;
    this.attr2 = 1;
  }

  firstMethod(){ // I wish to replace old method with this one, using the same name
    console.log("test2");
  }
}
```

I wish for this `mySecondClass` to have all the properties and methods from `myFirstClass` but to replace the type of some properties and replace some functions, in this example I wish to change:

attr1 from string to boolean
firstMethod() from outputting [console.log("test1");] to [console.log("test2");]

[Typescript playground, click here for an example of this same code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEBbAngMQJYCcYGFp3gG9R54oAXczARngC54Yr0A7AcwG4SzLMAmBiwCuiAEYBTTFxDcwAexZNMQsOTmYAFAEpiIUqXIALdDAB0FKrQC88AOTlxTW9P3wjJ87z7wb1F-ABfUFAgmXB8BBQAZXF5FgATPFgEcQAPBwTItCxcCKJuCxoGUTk5CHEoFmlZBSUVNU0dblIYIQAHSW1-A2MzQus3ZXFut17PKm9ff1CAoA)

is there a way to do this?

Comment: `I wish to replace old method with this one, using the same name` nothing wrong there

Comment: `I wish to update the type of this variable` the only way I know is to make `attr1: any` in `myFirstClass` or even `attr1: string|boolean`

Comment: @JaromandaX thing is I'm trying to extend the functionality of a third party library which I cannot modify at all, so I have no access to that code in a way fo saying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override parent class properties typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434444/override-parent-class-properties-typescript)

Comment: If I understand the question right, then it seems that @JaromandaX is correct.

Comment: If you can't change the "base" class, then you're out of luck

Comment: You wish to overload a variable of one type, with a variable of another type....

Why not just declare and use a different variable?

Comment: You'd be breaking the type hierarchy (e.g., a `MySecondClass` instance would no longer be assignable to `MyFirstClass`, despite being `instanceof MyFirstClass`) but you could do it by widening the apparent type of the superclass constructor like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOAd6m). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be an orthodox way of doing that (with good reason), but TS can be coerced into doing some very shady things for Javascript interoperability.

I provide this solution for learning purposes. I don't recommended actually using it unless you know what you're doing and you're absolutely certain there are no better options for your specific requirements.

```js
// First, declare a type for the subclass by modifying the super.
type mySecondClass = Omit<myFirstClass, "attr1" | "firstMethod"> & {
    attr1 : boolean
    // because `firstMethod` is an instance member function, the function signatures 
    // in the super and sub are different because they have different `this` types
    // and thus we must redefine it here.
    firstMethod () : void
}

// Now, implement the sub by extending the super, but make TS think
// that the super *looks* like the sub. 
const mySecondClass = class extends (myFirstClass as any as new () => mySecondClass) {

    constructor() {
        super()
        // this.attr1 will be a string at this point, but TS will not know that
        // because we lied to it. 
        this.attr1 = false
    }

    firstMethod() {
        console.log("test2")
    }
}

const fst = new myFirstClass()
const snd = new mySecondClass()

fst.firstMethod() // "test1"
snd.firstMethod() // "test2"

console.log(fst.attr1, snd.attr1) // "test", false
console.log(snd instanceof myFirstClass) // true
// @ts-expect-error  Type 'mySecondClass' is not assignable to type 'myFirstClass'
const ohno : myFirstClass = snd;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEC2CeAxAlgJwgFwMLitA3gFDQlgYaoCMAXNJqsgHYDmA3MaeagEy2MCusAEYBTVOw7RgAe0b1%20wDNNQAKAJRESW6BgAWyCADoyFStAC80AOQYRmK%2020k9B4124XolR9AC%20hDgAzNEwAWRE9aQATdU0tGTlpEBFDEGlmFQAiW0xKTLUff0IigHoS6BR0DAAaaCiRUDBUEWgwHXgABxbA5R1dFoh%20IUa8IXg4aORA%20CZmPoH%20LtRDQgxOloQAZQbZKJxIGEsAeVhkDAAeBErMfahazJMqTOgAH2hM4KrwyKjMgD5oAAyAiSVpcMy0ITSJIiMCMUFlaCiYBgfgQFoAA0%20YQiumiGOgBlajEJcgwcOAGxEwjE0EC-EYimQslqem6DKZsjoyGYjDI-GaMAR5SY8zoi1pcKi4qErWadSmgTEIkYGCRDVR6Pm410YAAbi0oorlaroBiXBACWsuhBhcTpXo0dAAO4bNFq5r1YKMFpnaD9ZorbTYjDfPHS9TQWh66TIKLFAKIgBy0mdtWQsA6yVgKrVbJlSPGIgAHrZGEaWGLBktakJ%20GrYGAANYtAAqmz6TCbhERejIVYlqGgACo0tImxBh9AQMgWwOhIZoIQEpg4PBtgk9rhDlJt9AS2WojAVFcQtg95BieNLz7ndBI%20YAVsduXbhA1CDQSuKAolKoP3ETjiks6igtovb6EYjxmM6yAgCA6qtHQFCzGCnYwB0saqrW9bQO2LpwQhjDSGqTbEXefYYGBWiIsimotK607ICIDrSISGCLtRziQW4pieIEYAgOioJFMGZ5htEkaAU4K4wqk6RZDkGDcPkIkJsusiroEq6WLea7XOeBygd%20dDlp4enPpub6gYQ2kcSGEkxB%20iLZHYGB5IQEDloYDm4pJznlK5mAqQEsnJPJGR2bxVC1F5UTRZQAXvEpmS1AJQkiBpiThWkGRxaSmAUiI0iBPpZ5vklP6ZYiAACGAQAAtCWXSKE1qCoL0eHrNYlm7G%20ViEjAxFqgcPJ8kIyQ6Gx1otFYp5VP1WWrtIujEVGZULXulhxewQA)